# Why is publishDir not copying large directories?

Tags: output, threadpool, nextflow, publishdir

I am using publishDir to copy an output directory (that has subdirectories) from my Cellranger process to a specified directory. For smaller output directories, this works, but not for a larger one (14G total). I am using the Slurm executor and using a shared file system.

What I've tried so far:

- I have cleared the cache
- Changed my OpenJDK to Corretto (it was previously JetBrains)
- Tried another file system
- Tried other runs of the same size from the same directory
- Tried smaller runs (successful)

Here is my nextflow script:

```
params.run_dir = ''
params.sample_id = ''
params.csv = ''
params.workflow = ''
params.gex_outdir = '/work/srb108/GEX'


process makefastq_gex {
    cache 'lenient'
    beforeScript 'module load Cell-Ranger/7.2.0'
    publishDir "${params.gex_outdir}", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path run_dir
    val sample_id
    path csv
    
    output:
    path "${sample_id}_mkfastq_outs"

    script:
    """
    cellranger mkfastq --run=${run_dir} --csv=${csv} --output-dir=${sample_id}_mkfastq_outs --delete-undetermined
    """

} 


workflow {
    run_dir = Channel.fromPath(params.run_dir)
    sample_id = params.sample_id
    csv = Channel.fromPath(params.csv)
    workflow = params.workflow

    if(params.workflow == "gex") {
        makefastq_gex(run_dir, sample_id, csv)
    }  
    
}
```

Here is my config file:

```
workDir = '/work/srb108'

process {
    executor = 'slurm'

    withName: makefastq_gex {
        cpus = 10
        memory = '250 GB'
        clusterOptions = '--partition=dhvi --job-name=test_mkfastq_job --mail-type=END --mail-user=srb108@duke.edu'
    }

}
```

This is the ending portion of a log file for a run in which publishDir was SUCCESSFUL:

```
Mar-18 14:52:11.105 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.util.ThreadPoolBuilder - Creating thread pool 'PublishDir' minSize=10; maxSize=10; workQueue=LinkedBlockingQueue[10000]; allowCoreThreadTimeout=false
Mar-18 14:52:11.254 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all processes finished
Mar-18 14:52:11.280 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - <<< barrier arrives (monitor: slurm) - terminating tasks monitor poll loop
Mar-18 14:52:11.285 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all barriers passed
Mar-18 14:52:16.328 [main] INFO  nextflow.util.ThreadPoolHelper - Waiting for file transfers to complete (1 files)
^ THIS LINE REPEATS A FEW TIMES
Mar-18 14:58:42.520 [main] DEBUG nextflow.util.ThreadPoolManager - Thread pool 'PublishDir' shutdown completed (hard=false)
Mar-18 14:58:43.105 [main] DEBUG n.trace.WorkflowStatsObserver - Workflow completed > WorkflowStats[succeededCount=1; failedCount=0; ignoredCount=0; cachedCount=0; pendingCount=0; submittedCount=0; runningCount=0; retriesCount=0; abortedCount=0; succeedDuration=7h 41m 42s; failedDuration=0ms; cachedDuration=0ms;loadCpus=0; loadMemory=0; peakRunning=1; peakCpus=10; peakMemory=100 GB; ]
Mar-18 14:58:43.731 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cache.CacheDB - Closing CacheDB done
Mar-18 14:58:44.215 [main] DEBUG nextflow.util.ThreadPoolManager - Thread pool 'FileTransfer' shutdown completed (hard=false)
Mar-18 14:58:44.216 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Execution complete -- Goodbye
```

However, I do not see this ending portion for the runs whose results do not get published as indicated in this log file. These are the last few lines and that's it:

```
Mar-25 16:02:02.696 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - !! executor slurm > tasks to be completed: 1 -- submitted tasks are shown below
~> TaskHandler[jobId: 5508033; id: 1; name: makefastq_gex (1); status: RUNNING; exit: -; error: -; workDir: /work/srb108/3e/ec9f059261a38bd6ff58c6ced0911b started: 1711387919417; exited: -; ]
Mar-25 16:07:02.702 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - !! executor slurm > tasks to be completed: 1 -- submitted tasks are shown below
~> TaskHandler[jobId: 5508033; id: 1; name: makefastq_gex (1); status: RUNNING; exit: -; error: -; workDir: /work/srb108/3e/ec9f059261a38bd6ff58c6ced0911b started: 1711387919417; exited: -; ]
Mar-25 16:12:02.709 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - !! executor slurm > tasks to be completed: 1 -- submitted tasks are shown below
~> TaskHandler[jobId: 5508033; id: 1; name: makefastq_gex (1); status: RUNNING; exit: -; error: -; workDir: /work/srb108/3e/ec9f059261a38bd6ff58c6ced0911b started: 1711387919417; exited: -; ]
```

There is nothing in .command.err.

It looks like the publishDir thread pool is not being created for these larger runs. I'm at a loss for where to go from here.

Comment: Are the correct output files being created in each of the process work directories? And how big are the output files?

Comment: @dthorbur Yes, the correct output folders/files are being created in each of the process work directories. I am trying to publish the entire output folder (61 GB total) which has subfolders. It includes a subfolder that has the fastq's which make up almost all of the 61 GB. Each fastq file is anywhere from 2-4 GB. I originally thought it was only 14GB but looks like its more. Seems like I can't edit my post now.

Comment: `publishDir` usually looks for files rather than directories. I've had issues with large directories too, so a potential solution would be to gzip your output directory. This also makes things easier for downstream processes since they only need to input a single gzipped directory.

Comment: I've never tried to emit a whole directory in this manner, but alternative things to try could be `output: path "./${sample_id}_mkfastq_outs", type: dir`, or `output: path "./${sample_id}_mkfastq_outs/*"`, but the latter would emit all your output files only, but you can use the `saveAs` option to put it into different directories. This last option would be messy for any processes downstream.

Comment: @dthorbur I tried using the gzip method and output: path "./${sample_id}_mkfastq_outs", type: dir, but neither of those worked. I can try the last option you suggested, but as you said, that's pretty messy and I ideally would like to keep things organized as there are three subfolders that have different files in them.

Comment: Just checking, when you used the gzip idea, you changed the output declaration to find something like `./${sample_id}*.gz`?

Comment: @dthorbur Yes, I changed the output declaration to: path "./${sample_id}_mkfastq_outs.tar.gz". The folder is indeed compressed but never gets moved with publishDir unless its a smaller directory. I tried this for a run with an output directory of 30GB and it published accordingly, but not for one that is 53 GB. Seems strange, that's not a huge size difference. And this is only using 1 lane for cellranger, normally we use 8.

Comment: 40GB doesn't get published either.

Comment: This is likely linked to options on how your cluster admins have set up nextflow options. Might be worth talking to them. What's odd to me is that you are not getting errors when file transfer is incomplete, instead jobs appear to just stop.

Comment: @dthorbur
Yeah I'm going to reach out to them. Strange enough, I decided to create my own mock directory of 50gb worth of data on my local computer and then scp it over to the cluster. I created a scratch nextflow script where I compress the directory and publishDir successfully publishes that directory. I don't understand why it's not getting published when I compress the output after the cellranger process in the original script. Edit: I tried to create 50gb worth of data using a bash script on the cluster but it was taking over 7 hours to complete so I did it locally instead.